# Citrix Workspace is not connecting to Virtual machine from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: citrix

I am trying to setup Citrix workspace on my Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded the latest packages from the official website, tried both deb and tar package installations. When I try to connect to my Virtual machine, I get the below pop up.

[image: Error Pop up]

Is there anyone who is successfully using Citrix workspace in 20.04? If yes, please share the installation steps you followed.

Also I am not sure if the issues is from Citrix end or from Virtual machine end, after entering the credentials citrix is able to authenticate and identify the VM, but when trying to connect it throws error.